# Invoke blackberry map using webworks api

Tags: jquery, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I want to invoke native blackberry map application using webworks project.I am using BB10 jquery theme.can anyone suggest some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke BB Maps and display a set of coordinates, you could use the blackberry.launch. object method as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var workAddress = 
    { 
        "address1": "1600 Pennsylvania Ave.", 
        "city": "Washington", 
        "country": "USA", 
        "stateProvince": "DC", 
        "zipPostal": "20500" 
    }; 
blackberry.launch.newMap({ "address": workAddress });
```

A quick reference is - http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18446/blackberry_launch_971534_11.jsp#blackberry_launch_newTask_972689_11

For other maps support in BB 10, you can check - https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/Maps